# Syntax error in my from clause

Tags: java, syntax-error, sqlexception

Im getting this :
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.
For my code:

```
ResultSet results = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM User" + "WHERE user_name = '" + 
                    txtUser.getText() + "'AND password = '" + txtPass.getText() + "'" );
```

I have already declared all of the variables, and i suspect the error has something to do with the structure however I am unsure. Thanks

Comment: You're missing a space between `User` and `WHERE`.

Comment: Oh! That worked perfectly! Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pay close attention to your code on this line:

```
"SELECT * FROM User" + "WHERE user_name
```

You can see that this results in

```
SELECT * FROM UserWHERE user_name
```

You need to add in a space.

In addition you're opening yourself to SQL injection attacks by building your statement like this.  You should really use a `PreparedStatement` and use placeholder.  You also won't need to build the statement by hand which would help you avoid this very issue.